# Django: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder (extends tag)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hlR.png) when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I've gone through other similar threads and have tried playing around with spaces as well as single and double quotation marks but with no luck.
I'm trying to have the index.html file inherit the code in master.html, which is contained in a folder structure that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfta7.png).

Here are a few snippets of some of the files that I think are causing this error:

from **settings.py:**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tracker',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

from **index.html** (this is the only line in this file)

`{% extends ‘layouts/master.html’ %}`

from **views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Error traceback:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '‘layouts/master.html’' from '‘layouts/master.html’'
```

What seems to be causing the syntax error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `{% extends ‘layouts/master.html’ %}` use `{% extends 'layouts/master.html' %}`

Comment: thanks! that solved the issue. however, that symbol doesn't appear to be a character easily accessed from the keyboard...or am I missing something